# What is the equivalent of an Python ASCII encoded byte string in C/C++ when dealing with sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a mediocre background on C and C++ socket programming.

For the time being as part of a project I had to check socket programming in Python 3.
I was taking a look at the following example :
https://support.mecademic.com/support/solutions/articles/64000253388-python-example-simple-tcp-ip-socket-client

Regarding the command `client.send(bytes(cmd+'\0','ascii'))`
I understand that if one works with low level data connections like network sockets Python 3 transfers data as byte strings: data type bytes.

All of a sudden I was thinking what how this command would be implemented by a c/c++ client but I got confused with the encoding/decoding part of the buffers.

Let's take for example the following clients which are based on poco library

https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/25852263/

In all the examples the  buffers are char arrays.

What I'd like to ask is that if someone would like to replace the python client with a
c++ like one of the above, then the sending and receiving part remains the same ?

e.x

```
int n = ss.sendBytes("hello", 5);
char buffer[256];
n = ss.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Meaning that by default the C char arrays are ascii encoded?

Or should before sending the buffer to convert for example the ascii string to byte array as in the following example:

https://www.includehelp.com/c/convert-ascii-string-to-byte-array-in-c.aspx

Accordingly the reception needs any decoding as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Please tell me if I am understanding your question correctly. You are trying to send and receive bytes. If your API takes a `char[]` array, then you should not convert the individual characters into bytes.

For example, you would pass "C8ICS33" not "43 38 49 43 53 33 33".

Sometimes in c++, API will take a `std::uint8_t[]` or `std::byte[]` array instead of a character. `std::uint8_t` is just an unsigned integer the size of a byte. std::byte is a bit more complex, but usually no one uses them.

**So TL;DR: don't convert your char[] to "bytes"**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in C and C++ the char arrays typically hold ASCII (or UTF-8, which can be thought of as a backward-compatible superset of ASCII as far as C-style strings are concerned) by default, so there isn’t any need to encode or decode those types of strings.